# use of constants without grouping in a class in C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to use constants without grouping them in a class? I need to pass some constant configuration values as argument to a method. At this moment my code looks like this:

```
board.ADCConfig(board.AN0 | board.CH0 | board.TAD2 | board.FOSC6 | board.leftjust);
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
board.ADCConfig(AN0 | CH0 | TAD2 | FOSC16 | leftjust);
```

Grouping all the constants in a separate file.

Comment: Make them an Enum values with `Flags` attribute, saved in separate file.

Comment: maybe should use enums or structure and organize them

Comment: can you make a separate constant for `board.AN0 | board.CH0 | board.TAD2 | board.FOSC6 | board.leftjust`

Comment: Already two comments says use `Enum`. I second them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# requires everything to be defined within a class so you can't do anything about it.

In the upcoming C# 6 there is a [new construct](http://csharp.2000things.com/2014/10/29/1214-c-6-0-using-directive-with-static-class/) where you can use `using` with a class. With `using YourApp.board` the syntax you want would be possible.

Comment: @AndreasAbel could give us some hint about the new `using` usage? I have somehow no luck googling it :-(

Comment: well I was afraid of that, but I want to know if there was another way, thanks for the link @AndersAbel.